# how to invalidate a UIView in a Asynctask (swift, ios)

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-async

I have a UIView with a backgroundcolor.

`@IBOutlet var timelineview: Timelineview!`

Now I would like the change the background color of the `UIView` with an Asynctask which should change the backgroundcolor of the `UIView` every second.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        for var i=10;i<100;i++ {
            println(i);
            var iRed:CGFloat=CGFloat(i)/CGFloat(10.0);
            var backgroundColor:UIColor=UIColor(red: iRed, green: iRed, blue: iRed, alpha: 0.5);
            self.timelineview.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

This is only a sample to understand how to invoke a change to the GUI from a background task. In Android this is done with handlers, which are updating the GUI. I don't know the concept in IOS doing this.

Any help ?

Comment: You could be using `NSTimer` instead of `dispatch_async`/`sleep` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is not a dispatch queue, rather a timer that can be created using `dispatch_source_create` method of GCD, like following:

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main-queue());

//start timer
if (timer) {
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
        // set background color or any other UI code here
    });
    dispatch_resume(timer);
}
```

`interval` is the interval in seconds in which the timer should fire (1.0 for you)
To stop the timer use:

```
dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
timer = NULL;
```

I am sorry, that I am a plain old Objective C guy and not much familiar with Swift. But you might get the concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. This is promising. I will checkout. Also the answer from Ian MacDonald is good and I already checked. So I am not sure who to accept the answer for the moment :-)

Comment: @user1344545 I can understand the dilemma. But I should recommend you at least one thing like Ian McDonald has mentioned at some point of his answer, avoid calling `sleep` in your code unless if you don't have any other means to perform the same functionality. For your requirement, a timer is a pretty optimal solution. You could also use `NSTimer` if you find that more compelling.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have overridden the behaviour of your view, setting the `backgroundColor` also tells the view it needs to redisplay. If you are finding that it doesn't work (it should), you can explicitly tell a view to redisplay by using

```
self.timelineview.setNeedsDisplay()
```

**Side note**: You should *never* call `sleep` in the main queue.

---

It looks like you want it to continually update its colour every second. This loop should not exist on the main queue; the contents may exist on it, though. Instead, consider something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
  for var i=10;i<100;i++ {
    println(i);
    var iRed:CGFloat=CGFloat(i)/CGFloat(10.0);
    var backgroundColor:UIColor=UIColor(red: iRed, green: iRed, blue: iRed, alpha: 0.5);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())) {
      self.timelineview.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

It's still not a great idea to queue this whole block at once (even if you're queuing to the background queue). You should do it with a repeating timer or a display link.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Thats helpfull.. I tested and it worked very well. Abviously its not a good design as you also mentoined and I will also checkout the answer from Ayan. So I am not sure who to accept the answer for the moment :-)

Comment: Upvoted, because it answers my question, but ayans answer fits a bit better. thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates/Main Queue

    });
});
```